# Instance variables vs. lazy loading method

Tags: ruby

I was wondering what the difference is between directly reference an instance variable and calling a method that returns the same instance variable.

Let us take the following block:

```
def some_method
  return @var if @var.present?
  ...
end
```

Function-wise there is no difference between referencing `@var` and calling `some_method`. Both will return the same value (assuming we are in the same instance).

```
def another_method
  var = @var
end
```

will work equally as:

```
def yet_another_method
  var = some_method
end
```

How do these approaches differ from each other? When the last could be better?

Comment: You cannot call `@var`. You have to call `instance_variable_get :@var`.

Comment: What do you mean by *"calling @var"*? Give an example.

Comment: How can this be unclear when 2 people have answered the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrap an instance variable in a method when you do not want to get exactly the instance variable, but a little more than that. For example, if you want to memoize, then instead of calling

```
@foo
```

rather you need to put it in a method and call it

```
def foo; @foo ||= ... end
foo ...
```

Or if you want to return a different value than the variable's when the variable takes a certain value, then you need to put a condition in it

```
def foo
  if @foo == ... then ... else @foo end
end
foo ...
```

Comment: I think `def foo; @foo ||= ... end` makes more sense as method that takes at least one argument (setter in this case) `def foo arg1; @foo ||= arg1 end`

Comment: @DarekNędza If it were a setter, it does not need memoization.

Answer (score 0):

`@bonus` is wrapped in a method, you can change what `bonus` means by implementing your own method. This helps you organize the code to allow for easy changes and enables you to depend on the behaviour rather than data.

```
class Pay
  attr_accessor :bonus

  def initialize(b)
    @bonus = b
  end

  def bonus
    @bonus = 100 if @bonus > 100    
  end
end
```